# Is there a tool or an approach that will give us the code coverage of a Java app by running the UI functional tests written using selenium with python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, code-coverage, jacoco, test-coverage, clover

We have a an application built using Java.
The JUnit tests are run and configured with JaCoCo to get the code coverage of the unit tests.

We have our testframework built using Python with Selenium for UI Functional Tests and Python Requests Library to cover API tests.

We are unable to get the Code Coverage by running API and Functional Tests.

Please let me know if you are using any such tool/ following any approach to read the code coverage percentage.

Thanks.

We did explore many tools such as Jacoco, OpenClover, cobertura but we could not find any working example

Answer (score 0):

Jacoco captures coverage of any Java application. Launch application under test with VM argument:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/jacoco/agent.jar=destfile=/output/directory/jacoco.exec,append=true
```